# Navbar transpraent on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my navbar to go transparent on scroll, nothing seem to be working. Her'es the code I've been using. Any suggestions?

```js
//transparent scroll

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop()>100)
    $(".navbar").css({"background-color" : "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"});

    else
    $(".navbar").css({"background-color" : "transparent"});


    });

});

CSS
```

```css
/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: $back-two;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #979797;
}

/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: $textcol;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 15px;
}

//hover
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s; 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid $accent;                    
}

//focus
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: $back-two;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $accent;  
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
}


HTML
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Ross Finn</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#work">Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#tf-contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Working good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 100) {    
        $(".navbar").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
        });
    } else {
        $(".navbar").css({
            "background-color": "transparent"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: the scroll is not an event thats good for something like this, when you scroll the wheel the even is actually being fired several times, this would be better done with a timeout